# Reasons to have a return statement without returning any value

Tags: python, return

The following code came from the book [Fundamentals of Python](https://www.booktopia.com.au/fundamentals-of-python-kenneth-lambert/book/9781337560092.html?source=pla&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvL-oBhCxARIsAHkOiu0hyMQneJ9G_uPeEKaq8o6qtQVSxkqqokBDKkawFDitkWNIoLc4HuUaAkbIEALw_wcB), which made me think there *must* be some reasons for the author to use `return` without returning anything.

```
def save(self, fileName = None):
    """Saves pickled accounts to a file. The parameter
    allows the user to change filenames."""
    if fileName != None:
        self.fileName = fileName
    elif self.fileName == None:
        return # WHAT ARE THE REASONS FOR HAVING THIS LINE? CAN WE DELETE/REMOVE IT?
    fileObj = open(self.fileName, "wb")
    for account in self.accounts.values():
        pickle.dump(account, fileObj)
    fileObj.close()
```

The full code is as follows:

```
import pickle

class SavingsAccount(object):
    RATE = 0.02 # Single rate for all accounts
    
    def __init__(self, name, pin, balance = 0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        self.balance = balance
    
    def __str__(self) :
        """Returns the string rep."""
        result = 'Name: ' + self.name + '\n'
        result += 'PIN: ' + self.pin + '\n'
        result += 'Balance: ' + str(self.balance)
        return result
    
    def getBalance(self):
        """Returns the current balance."""
        return self.balance
    
    def getName(self):
        """Returns the current name."""
        return self.name
    
    def getPin(self):
        """Returns the current pin."""
        return self.pin
    
    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the given amount and returns None."""
        self.balance += amount
        return None
    
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """Withdraws the given amount.
        Returns None if successful, or an
        error message if unsuccessful."""
        if amount < 0:
            return "Amount must be >= 0"
        elif self.balance < amount:
            return "Insufficient funds"
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return None
    
    def computeInterest(self):
        """Computes, deposits, and returns the interest."""
        interest = self.balance * SavingsAccount.RATE
        self.deposit(interest)
        return interest
    

class Bank(object):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.accounts = {}
        self.fileName = fileName
        
    def __str__(self) :
        """Return the string rep of the entire bank."""
        return '\n'.join(map(str, self.accounts.values()))

    def makeKey(self, name, pin):
        """Makes and returns a key from name and pin."""
        return name + "/" + pin

    def add(self, account):
        """Inserts an account with name and pin as a key."""
        key = self.makeKey(account.getName(),  account.getPin())
        self.accounts[key] = account
        
    def remove(self, name, pin):
        """Removes an account with name and pin as a key."""
        key = self.makeKey(name, pin)
        return self.accounts.pop(key, None)
    
    def get(self, name, pin):
        """Returns an account with name and pin as a key
        or None if not found."""
        key = self.makeKey(name, pin)
        return self.accounts.get(key, None)
    
    def computeInterest(self):
        """Computes interest for each account and
        returns the total."""
        total = 0.0
        for account in self.accounts.values():
            total += account.computeInterest()
        return total
    
    def save(self, fileName = None):
        """Saves pickled accounts to a file. The parameter
        allows the user to change filenames."""
        if fileName != None:
            self.fileName = fileName
        elif self.fileName == None:
            return
        fileObj = open(self.fileName, "wb")
        for account in self.accounts.values():
            pickle.dump(account, fileObj)
        fileObj.close()
```

How can the `def save(self, fileName=None)` be modified such that the program will ask user to provide a file name, that is:

```
bank = Bank(None)
bank.add(SavingsAccount("Wilma", "1001", 4000.00))
bank.add(SavingsAccount("Fred", "1002", 1000.00))
bank.save() # a prompt would appear: 'Please provide a name for the file to be saved'
```

Comment: If we _didn't_ have the `return None`, then the code would try to run `open(None, "wb")` when `self.fileName == None`, which would throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `return` followed by no value is the same as writing `return None`. In the code you've shown, the `return` statement is used to terminate the function in the case that no filename is passed, rather than trying to execute the code following the `if` and `elif`.

Comment: It's called an "early exit", and sometimes even coding standards that prohibit returns in the middle of a function will allow this.

Comment: This is only answering half the question. (Granted, that's because the OP tried to ask two unrelated questions in one "question" -- but per the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), questions that "request answers to multiple questions" are better closed than answered altogether).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question, ndc85430. Much appreciated. Why did the author use `return None` instead of asking a user to provide a file name (which would be much better I think)?

Comment: Don't know, you'd have to ask them. It's not a design I would have chosen.